React 19, server components setup using vite
I hope you are doing well.
I tried to setup React 19 using vite. First I created the vite/react template and then upgraded react and react-dom.
When trying to use Server components through async component, I am getting this error: "async/await is not
yet supported in Client Components, only Server Components. This error is often caused by accidentally adding 'use client' to a module that was originally written for the server. Error Component Stack".
Starter code is almost empty:
export default async function App() {
    return <div>Starter template</div>;
}

I know that I need a server to setup server components. I can use Nextjs for that, but according to React docs, It says we can use server components without the server and during build time(which can be considered as a server)
Am I missing something?
Thanks in advance.
